# Adjusting categorical household income variable for interaction effects

Tags: stata, randomized-experiment, heterogeneity

For a research project (RCT) I am working on, I'm trying to identifying how different demographic groups differed in their performance on certain indices over time (like finance, health etc - measured via monthly surveys) and how that may have interacted with treatment groups these participants (randomized into 6 different treatment groups). Therefore, the main DV are four indices and the main IV are certain demographic characteristics from our participant pool.

I had no issues calculating the income effects for all the variables EXCEPT household income (HHInc2019) - which is the total self-reported household income of the participants in the year 2019.

```
              HHINC |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
--------------------+-----------------------------------
  Less than 10,000$ |      3,826       27.26       27.26
10,000$-20,000$ |      3,251       23.16       50.42
  20,000$ - 30,000$ |      2,774       19.76       70.18
   30,000 - 40,000$ |      1,685       12.00       82.19
  40,000$ - 50,000$ |        941        6.70       88.89
  50,000$ - 60,000$ |        527        3.75       92.65
  60,000$ - 70,000$ |        325        2.32       94.96
  70,000$ - 80,000$ |        212        1.51       96.47
  80,000$ - 90,000$ |        151        1.08       97.55
 90,000$ - 100,000$ |        101        0.72       98.27
100,000$ - 110,000$ |         88        0.63       98.90
110,000$ - 120,000$ |         35        0.25       99.15
  120,000$ or above |        120        0.85      100.00
--------------------+-----------------------------------
              Total |     14,036      100.00
```

**What I'm stuck on:** I want to adjust this variable based on the zip code of the participants but I'm not sure how to do this! I merged my dataset with the ACS survey with median household income by zip code, but how can I now adjust this categorical variable based on what I have?

Alternatively - would it work if I just use the ACS income variable as a control in my interaction effects model?